# How to position text block over a image?

Tags: html, css, image, text

I have tries to lay text block over image in my `HTML` website. I have Googled the Internet for a while, and luckily found 4 methods as follows:

```html
<!--method 1 -->
<div style="position: relative; background: url(hknight.jpg); width: 738px; height: 284px;">
 <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0.5em; width: 400px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;">
  <p>(text to appear at the bottom left of the image)</p>
 </div>

 <p style="position: absolute; top: 1em; right: 2em; width: 120px; padding: 4px; background-color: #fff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px;"> (text to appear at the top right of the image) </p>
</div>

<!--method 2 -->
<div style="background:url({{site.baseurl}}assets/hknight.jpg) no-repeat;width:738px;height:284px;text-align:center">
 <span style="color:#fcc">some text...</span>
</div>

<!--method 3 -->
<div style="position:relative; width: 738px; height: 284px">
 <span style="position:absolute; left:50; bottom:50; color:#fff; font-weight:bold">some text</span>
 <img src="hknight.jpg">
</div>

<!--method 4 -->
<TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="5" CELLSPACING="0">
  <TR>
    <TD WIDTH="738" HEIGHT="284" BACKGROUND="hknight.jpg" VALIGN="bottom">
      <FONT SIZE="+1" COLOR="yellow">some text ...</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

But none of the four methods generate the desired effects as I wish. You can refer to the folowing figures.
[image]
The 1st method can position text block accurately over the image. However, the image cannot adapt to the screen automatically. For example, if I visit the web page from smart phone, only the left part of the image is displayed. By the way, you can see that the border is like a square with sharp angle.
[image]
The 2nd method is similar to the 1st one except that text block cannot be laid accurately.
[image]
The 3rd method adapts the image automatically to screen. The border shows curve lines which looks very good. But I cannot position the text accurately. As you see, in my code I use `left:50; bottom:50;` which comes out with text bock only at the top left corner.
[image]
The 4th method is special with `table`. The problem is similar to the 1st method in that it borders are sharp and cannot adapt to screen. What is worse, the image is smaller than its original size though I specified the true `width` and `height`.

Can you think of a better solution meeting my requirements?

---

**EDIT 1**:
For method  3 if I choose `em` as the position parameter, it works now! I don't know why `pixel` doesn't show text at the specified position.

**EDIT 2**:
My requirements:

1. The image border lines should be curve.
2. The text block should be accurately positioned as I will.
3. The image can adapt to the screen automatically.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It is not a problem but an effect I prefer.

Comment: "`However, the image cannot adapt to the screen automatically`" if you set `width: 738px; height: 284px;` how you expect the element to be responsive?

Comment: also (demo 1) `background: hknight.jpg` will not work cause bg img needs an `url()`

Comment: you might want to add `max-width: 100%` to your code to make it responsive.

Comment: P.S: It would be wise, instead of explaining what you want trough four examples of ***what you actually don't want***... to explain short ***what you actually want***

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If you don't include the `width` and `height`, the image will disappear from my website. BTW, I added the argument `url`.

Comment: Related to your edit: `left:50; bottom:50;` are NOT pixels... it's *nothing*. while `left:0;` is perfectly valid, `left: 50;` is not since it misses a unit.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I added my requirements. I should have included `px` for `left: 50`.

Comment: @Anubhav Where should I put the `max-width:100%` in my code? For which method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the image flow vertically inside an `overflow:hidden` positioned parent.
Position the `absolute` texts at wish.

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.box img{
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom,
.right{
  margin:1em;
  position:absolute;
}
.bottom{
  bottom: 0px;
}
.right{
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  
  <img src="http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/119132/city-lights-building-night.jpg">
  
  <p class="bottom">(text to appear at the bottom left of the image)</p>
  <p class="right"> (text to appear at the top right of the image)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `.bottom{bottom:0;}` and `.right{right:0;}` is used here?

Comment: @Zachary for the sole purpose of showing you that you can change that value to anything you need like `bottom: 20px;` or `left:50px;` should not be difficult! Also if you remove `bottom:0;` entirely, you'd pretty much answer your own question.

Comment: If I need to insert two images with different size in my web page. Then `.imgBg` does not work since the `height` problem.

Comment: I accept your answer. It is very good. Every time I need to insert a figure in my web page. I just need to modify the `img` tag. Tow comments: **1** `background url` bad for my requirement. **2** In order to position image anywhere over the image, I think the answer should be changed a little bit. For example, define a `.posotion {top:0px, bottom:0px, left:0px, right:0px)`

Comment: @Zachary we're not here to fix pixels, but to give you an idea for you to move forward with your task! My answer covers hopefully all your 3 requirements. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: See your point. But could you explain why need `overflow:hidden`? If you change `hidden` to `visible`, the text will be  at a little bit higher place over the image. I guess `hidden` will make the `margin` parameter does not work at least at the bottom edge.

Comment: @Zachary the only thing I can see by removing `overflow:hidden` is the inner image overlap the DIV parent (the border-radius will not be visible due to the now overlapping image). `I guess hidden will make the margin parameter does not work` is not true, don't guess. Test! Copy-paste my code in http://jsbin.com to quickly edit and see the changes if it helps.